# error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

I am having this errors while login in the app when HomeClient.java class is called....I am developing the Taxy calling App and i have used Sliding drawer and Map too....

```
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fenixcar/com.example.fenixcar.HomeClient}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at com.example.fenixcar.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:61)
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5113)
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     ... 11 more
02-02 14:26:40.627: W/ActivityManager(293):   Force finishing activity com.example.fenixcar/.HomeClient
02-02 14:26:40.637: W/ActivityManager(293):   Force finishing activity com.example.fenixcar/.Login
02-02 14:26:41.147: W/ActivityManager(293): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{415c5030 u0 com.example.fenixcar/.HomeClient}
02-02 14:26:41.168: I/Choreographer(293): Skipped 127 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-02 14:26:41.197: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
02-02 14:26:41.378: D/dalvikvm(293): GC_CONCURRENT freed 452K, 62% free 5039K/13004K, paused 143ms+58ms, total 855ms
02-02 14:26:41.438: I/Choreographer(538): Skipped 119 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-02 14:26:41.598: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
02-02 14:26:41.708: I/Choreographer(538): Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-02 14:26:41.948: I/Choreographer(293): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-02 14:26:41.998: I/Choreographer(293): Skipped 107 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-02 14:26:52.076: W/ActivityManager(293): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{40d257a8 u0 com.example.fenixcar/.Login}
02-02 14:26:52.078: W/ActivityManager(293): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{415c5030 u0 com.example.fenixcar/.HomeClient}
02-02 14:26:56.236: D/ExchangeService(756): Received deviceId from Email app: null
02-02 14:26:56.237: D/ExchangeService(756): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
02-02 14:27:01.318: D/ExchangeService(756): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
02-02 14:27:01.328: D/ExchangeService(756): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
02-02 14:27:01.338: D/ExchangeService(756): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
02-02 14:27:01.348: W/ActivityManager(293): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
02-02 14:27:01.348: D/ExchangeService(756): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
02-02 14:27:01.358: W/ActivityManager(293): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
02-02 14:27:01.378: E/ActivityThread(756): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d40878 that was originally bound here
02-02 14:27:01.378: E/ActivityThread(756): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d40878 that was originally bound here
02-02 14:27:01.378: E/ActivityThread(756):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-02 14:27:01.378: E/ActivityThread(756):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-02 14:27:01.378: E/ActivityThread(756):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-02 14:27:01.378: E/ActivityThread(756):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-02 14:27:01.378: E/ActivityThread(756):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-02 14:27:01.378: E/ActivityThread(756):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-02 14:27:01.378: E/ActivityThread(756):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-02 14:27:01.378: E/ActivityThread(756):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
02-02 14:27:01.378: E/ActivityThread(756):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
02-02 14:27:01.378: E/ActivityThread(756):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
02-02 14:27:01.378: E/ActivityThread(756):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-02 14:27:01.378: E/ActivityThread(756):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-02 14:27:01.378: E/ActivityThread(756):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-02 14:27:01.378: E/ActivityThread(756):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-02 14:27:01.378: E/ActivityThread(756):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-02 14:27:01.378: E/ActivityThread(756):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-02 14:27:01.378: E/ActivityThread(756):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-02 14:27:01.468: E/StrictMode(756): null
02-02 14:27:01.468: E/StrictMode(756): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d40878 that was originally bound here
02-02 14:27:01.468: E/StrictMode(756):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-02 14:27:01.468: E/StrictMode(756):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-02 14:27:01.468: E/StrictMode(756):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-02 14:27:01.468: E/StrictMode(756):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-02 14:27:01.468: E/StrictMode(756):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-02 14:27:01.468: E/StrictMode(756):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-02 14:27:01.468: E/StrictMode(756):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-02 14:27:01.468: E/StrictMode(756):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
02-02 14:27:01.468: E/StrictMode(756):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
02-02 14:27:01.468: E/StrictMode(756):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
02-02 14:27:01.468: E/StrictMode(756):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-02 14:27:01.468: E/StrictMode(756):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-02 14:27:01.468: E/StrictMode(756):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-02 14:27:01.468: E/StrictMode(756):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-02 14:27:01.468: E/StrictMode(756):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-02 14:27:01.468: E/StrictMode(756):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-02 14:27:01.468: E/StrictMode(756):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-02 14:27:01.478: W/ActivityManager(293): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40f905a0
02-02 14:27:01.478: E/ActivityThread(756): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d404d0 that was originally bound here
02-02 14:27:01.478: E/ActivityThread(756): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d404d0 that was originally bound here
02-02 14:27:01.478: E/ActivityThread(756):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-02 14:27:01.478: E/ActivityThread(756):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-02 14:27:01.478: E/ActivityThread(756):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-02 14:27:01.478: E/ActivityThread(756):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-02 14:27:01.478: E/ActivityThread(756):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-02 14:27:01.478: E/ActivityThread(756):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-02 14:27:01.478: E/ActivityThread(756):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-02 14:27:01.478: E/ActivityThread(756):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
02-02 14:27:01.478: E/ActivityThread(756):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
02-02 14:27:01.478: E/ActivityThread(756):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-02 14:27:01.478: E/ActivityThread(756):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-02 14:27:01.478: E/ActivityThread(756):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-02 14:27:01.478: E/ActivityThread(756):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-02 14:27:01.478: E/ActivityThread(756):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-02 14:27:01.478: E/ActivityThread(756):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-02 14:27:01.478: E/ActivityThread(756):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-02 14:27:01.498: E/StrictMode(756): null
02-02 14:27:01.498: E/StrictMode(756): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d404d0 that was originally bound here
02-02 14:27:01.498: E/StrictMode(756):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-02 14:27:01.498: E/StrictMode(756):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-02 14:27:01.498: E/StrictMode(756):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-02 14:27:01.498: E/StrictMode(756):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-02 14:27:01.498: E/StrictMode(756):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-02 14:27:01.498: E/StrictMode(756):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-02 14:27:01.498: E/StrictMode(756):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-02 14:27:01.498: E/StrictMode(756):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
02-02 14:27:01.498: E/StrictMode(756):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
02-02 14:27:01.498: E/StrictMode(756):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-02 14:27:01.498: E/StrictMode(756):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-02 14:27:01.498: E/StrictMode(756):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-02 14:27:01.498: E/StrictMode(756):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-02 14:27:01.498: E/StrictMode(756):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-02 14:27:01.498: E/StrictMode(756):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-02 14:27:01.498: E/StrictMode(756):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**My HomeClient.java file is**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;




import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeClient extends Activity {



    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homeclient);


        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();

            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();

            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }




}
```

**My Xml file attatched to HomeClient.class is here**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**My HomeFragment is**

```
package com.example.fenixcar;


import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{
    GoogleMap mMap;
    Fragment f;
    TextView t;
    String address,country,postalcode,city;
    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cant connect to google play service", 10).show();    

        GPSTRacker gps = new GPSTRacker(getActivity());


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        t = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.text);

        MapFragment m = (MapFragment)getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
        mMap = m.getMap();
        if (gps.canGetLocation()){
            double lati = gps.latitude;
            double longi = gps.longitude;
            address=gps.getAddressLine(getActivity());
            country=gps.getCountryName(getActivity());
            postalcode=gps.getPostalCode(getActivity());
            city=gps.getLocality(getActivity());
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lati, longi)).title("You Are Here!/n"+address+" "+city+" "+postalcode+" "+country);
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(lati, longi)).zoom(6).build();

            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

         // adding marker
            mMap.addMarker(marker);


            t.setText(" "+address+" "+city+" "+country);

            /*city=gps.locality;
            country=gps.countryName;
            postalcode=gps.postalCode;

            ed.setText(""+address+" "+city+" "+postalcode+" "+country);*/


        }
        else{
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView()
    {
        try{
          MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
          FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
          ft.remove(fragment);
          ft.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
      super.onDestroyView();  
  }


}
```

Comment: paste code for HomeFragment

Comment: Please show the code of HomeFragment as that is where the error originates from.

Comment: Stacktrace clearly points to exact line of your code: `HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:61` - what is your problem to check and fix yourself?

Comment: i am posting HomeFragment please check

Answer (score 0):

You have a NullPointerException at line 61 of your java (you can check you code) within your onCreateView.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-02 14:26:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):    
at com.example.fenixcar.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:61)
```

I suspect here:

```
mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
```

I also suspect you check your getActionBar, if you test with an if, it will tell you:

say:

```
if(getActionBar()!=null) {
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(this, "NO ACTIONBAR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Why all the extra code?  Just put a breakpoint on that line and debug.  This is a lousy way to debug.